# select where left between - MySQL query to SQLite query

Tags: mysql, sql, string, sqlite, substring

In my Windows Form application written in C# I have SQLite database but I am new in SQLite, I am more familiar with MySql... Anyway, I need to translate into SQLite query this query that works perfectly with MySql:

```
SELECT account 
FROM dettbl 
WHERE
    LEFT(account, 10) BETWEEN '0' AND '999999ZZZZ' 
    AND ddline >= 0 AND ddline  <= 100;
```

account is type of string and ddline is int.

Comment: There is no LEFT function in SQLite. Use SUBSTR(): https://sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#substr

Answer (score 3):

To have this query running on SQLite, you just need to use `SUBSTR()` instead of `LEFT()`:

```
SELECT account 
FROM dettbl 
WHERE
    SUBSTR(account, 1, 10) BETWEEN '0' AND '999999ZZZZ' 
    AND ddline >= 0 AND ddline  <= 100;
```

Note: the conditions on `ddline` could be simplified as `ddline BETWEEN 0 and 100`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change `LEFT` function to `SUBSTR( string, start, length )`:

```
SELECT account 
FROM dettbl 
WHERE
    SUBSTR(account, 0, 10) BETWEEN '0' AND '999999ZZZZ' 
    AND ddline >= 0 AND ddline  <= 100;
```